# Footer items are not in one line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer with 2 images with hyperlinks, while using `justify-content: center` is centers it but it centers the image from the start of the image and not from the center of the image which makes it a little bit off to the left.
Also, the images are staking (not overlapping, but one and another one on the next line). While I want them to be in one line.

```css
.footer-contents {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-logo {
    position: relative;
    /* align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; */
    /* margin: 0 clamp(10px, 3vw, 30px); */
    /* top: 80px; */
    /* flex-basis: auto; */
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin: 5px;
    /* padding: 5px; */
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
    margin: 0 40%;
}
  
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-container bg-container">
            <div class="footer-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/twitter--v1.png" alt="" class="footer-logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <a href="https://instagram.com/">
                           <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/instagram-new--v1.png" alt="" class="footer-logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, there are a typo error. Your HTML has "footer-content" class and the CSS has a class named "footer-contents". Maybe this your unique problem.

But, if you only need 2 images centered, you can get this with less HTML and less CSS. Check this:

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-container bg-container">
            <div class="footer-content">
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                        <img src="./images/twitter-logo.png" alt="" class="footer-logo">
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://instagram.com/">
                       <img src="./images/instagram-logo.png" alt="" class="footer-logo">
                  </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

I remove row and column (I don't know if you need for other purposes) and simply use text-align:

```
.footer-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-logo {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
```

If you use a div, it has a display of block (fills all width) and your images are if different rows. You can use span or simply don't put the images in a div, like in my response.